# Unbounded ZK vs perfect ZK?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

In the "On the Non-malleability of the Fiat-Shamir Transform" article by [Faust et.al.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/704.pdf), there is a definition for unbounded NIZK. What unbounded means in this context? It does not look like perfect ZK because the distinguisher is PPT and not unbounded [as required here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59492/55097).

[image]

Comment: The only thing this could be, if not a typo, is that the prover is computationally unbounded.

Comment: @Lev, I've contacted the authors and the answer is "unbounded means that the distinguisher can obtain an unbounded (polynomial) number of proofs". I'll delete a question